# Textarea slow for logging

Tags: performance, qt, qml, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I have a Qt application and I'd like to show some log. I use a `TextArea`. However, if the log is large or the events come too fast the GUI can't draw  `Textarea` fast enough.

I have analyzed this problem with Qt Creator (QML Profiler) and if the log is large it takes 300 ms to draw the GUI. I use this software on a Raspberry Pi2.

Any ideas how to solve this? Should I use other QML controls? Thanks.

QML code:

```
TextArea {
    text: appHandler.rawCommunication
    readOnly: true        
}
```

C++ code:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString rawCommunication READ rawCommunication WRITE setrawCommunication NOTIFY rawCommunicationChanged)

void setrawCommunication(QString val)
{
    val.append("\n");
    val.append(m_rawCommunication);
    m_rawCommunication = val;
    emit rawCommunicationChanged(m_rawCommunication);
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use argument reference? `void setrawCommunication(QString &val)`

Comment: you probably also need to append the new text only in the TextArea, instead of changing it every time. So in C++ you just send the "new text", instead of appending forever to a QString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [view](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#displaying-data-with-views), like [`ListView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html). They [instantiate their delegates as needed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#example-usage), based on which data the view says it needs to show depending on the position the user is at in the list. This means that they perform much better for visualising large amounts of data than items like `TextArea`, which in your case is going to keep a massive, ever-growing string in memory.

Your [delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#delegate-prop) could then be a `TextArea`, so you'd have one editable block of text per log line. However, if you don't need styling, I'd recommend going with something a bit lighter, like [`TextEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html). Taking it one step further: if you don't need editable text, use plain old `Text`. Switching to these might not make much of a difference, but if you're still seeing slowness (and have lots of delegates visible at a time), it's worth a try.

Comment: I've solved it with listview ListView {
        model:logModel
        delegate: Text {            
            text:display;
        }
    }

Comment: @Wolfy82: care to elaborate with an updated version of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the `ListView` suggestion but it has several drawbacks:

- No easy way to keep the view positioned at the bottom when new output is added
- No selection across lines/delegates

So I ended up using a cached `TextArea`, updating once every second:

```js
TextArea {
    id: outputArea_text
    wrapMode: TextArea.Wrap
    readOnly: true
    font.family: "Ubuntu Mono, times"
    
    function appendText(text){
        logCache += text + "\n";
        update_timer.start();
    }
    
    property string logCache: ""
    
    Timer {
        id: update_timer
        // Update every second
        interval: 1000
        running: false
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: {
            outputArea_text.append(outputArea_text.logCache);
            outputArea_text.logCache = "";
        }
    }
    
    Component.onCompleted: {
        my_signal.connect(outputArea_text.appendText)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this approach:
create a c++ logger class 
append all logs to this class
and print them using some action, example a button click
this will solve your performance issue

### Example of code:

### Logger.h

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QObject>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QString>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QDebug>

class Logger : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Logger(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Logger();
    Q_INVOKABLE QStringList *getLogStream();
    Q_INVOKABLE void printLogStream();
    Q_INVOKABLE void appendLog(QString log);
    Q_INVOKABLE void log(QString log="");
    Q_INVOKABLE void log(QString fileName, QString log);
signals:

public slots:

private:
     QStringList* stringStream_;
};

#endif // LOGGER_H
```

### Logger.cpp

```
    #include "logger.h"

    Logger::Logger(QObject *parent) :
        QObject(parent),
        stringStream_(new QStringList)
    {
    }

     ~Logger(){
                if(stringStream_ != NULL)
                {
                    delete stringStream_;
                    stringStream_ = NULL;
                 }
              }
    QStringList* Logger::getLogStream(){
        return stringStream_;
    }

    void Logger::printLogStream()
    {
        QStringListIterator itr(*stringStream_);
            while (itr.hasNext())
    qDebug()<< itr.next()<<"\n";
    }

     void Logger::appendLog(QString log){
         stringStream_->push_back(log) ;
    }
void Logger::log(QString fileName,QString log)
{

#ifdef ENABLElogs

    fileName.push_front(" [");
    if(!fileName.contains(".qml"))
    {
        fileName.append(".qml]:");
    }
    qDebug()<<fileName<<log;
#else
    Q_UNUSED(log);
    Q_UNUSED(fileName);
#endif
}
void Logger::log(QString log)
{

#ifdef ENABLElogs
    qDebug()<<log;
#else
    Q_UNUSED(log);
#endif
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include "logger.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer *viewer = new QtQuick2ApplicationViewer;
    Logger* stream = new Logger;
    viewer->rootContext()->setContextProperty("Stream",stream);
    viewer->setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/project/main.qml"));
    viewer->showExpanded();


    return app.exec();
}
```

### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 800
    height: 480
    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Component.onCompleted: Stream.appendLog("Text object is completed")
    }
    Column{
        x:300
    Button{
        text:"append"
        onClicked: {
            Stream.appendLog("MouseArea object clicked")
        }
        Component.onCompleted: Stream.appendLog("Button object is completed")
    }
    Button{
        text:"logger"
        onClicked: {
         Stream.printLogStream()
        }
        Component.onCompleted: Stream.appendLog("Button logger object is completed")
    }
}


    TextArea{
        text:"blablabla"
        Component.onCompleted: Stream.appendLog("TextArea object is completed")
    }
    Component.onCompleted: Stream.appendLog("the main object is completed")
}
```

### project.pro

```
    #add this line
    # comment it, run qmake and recompile to disable logs
    DEFINES += ENABLElogs
```

using this approch you can stop all logs with a single line change when you want to release your soft

Answer (score 0):

However, I have included complete code, using "QAbstractListModel" for a Logging heavy data to QML

**listmodel.h**

```
#ifndef LISTMODEL_H
#define LISTMODEL_H
#include <QAbstractListModel>

class ListModel: public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ListModel();

   // Q_PROPERTY(QStringList logs READ name WRITE  nameChanged)
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant activate(int i);

private:
    QStringList m_list;
};

#endif // LISTMODEL_H
```

**listmodel.cpp**

```
#include "listmodel.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QHash>


ListModel::ListModel()
{
    QFile file("/home/ashif/LogFile");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug( "Log file open failed" );
    }
    bool isContinue = true;
    do
    {
        if(file.atEnd())
        {
            isContinue = false;
        }
         m_list.append(file.readLine());
    }
    while( isContinue);
}

int ListModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent ) const
{

    return m_list.count();
}
QVariant ListModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role ) const
{
    if(!index.isValid()) {
           return QVariant("temp");
       }
    return m_list.value(index.row());
}
QVariant ListModel::activate(int i)
{
    return m_list[i];
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true

    ListView
    {
        width: 200; height: 250
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model:mylistModel
        delegate: Text
        {
            text:mylistModel.activate(index)
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "logger.h"
#include "listmodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Logger myLogger;
    ListModel listModel;    
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("mylistModel", &listModel);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```