# How to display QML view( with scroll) to load and display multiline Text around 10 million lines from file

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have mylog.txt having 4MB (Total lines: 100000 to 150000) Need to load and display to QML view.

> I have Implemented in following way( But it has performance issue )
>
> > 1. Open file using QFile in C++
> > 2. Exported to QML using Q_PROPERTY( *QString*...
> > 3. Displayed in QML using "TextArea" using *text* property

with above approach, slow to scroll the TextArea

Can anyone have idea on how to improve this using TextArea ?

or

Any other Control/approach, so that i can scroll large multi-line text without much performance issue.

Comment: Try to use model-view approach for this. Load data to string list model and show data in ListView. This will dynamically load element and would be faster.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345096/textarea-slow-for-logging/31347612#31347612