# TextArea QML 5.13 component is very slow with large text

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

`TextArea` is very slow with large data (more than 100 line, 200 character per line).

```js
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Window 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640; height: 480
    color: "gray"
    TextArea
    {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height / 2

        color: "black"
        clip: true
    }
}
```

I also change the `renderType` to `Text.QtRendering` and `Text.NativeRendering`, But is not work. How to fix it ?

Comment: How do you see that it is *very slow*?

Comment: @eyllanesc, When try to add more text typing, it's act very slowly.

Comment: Here you have some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345096/textarea-slow-for-logging